# admin panel in drupal 7 wont let me choose until I refresh

Tags: drupal-7

So I was messing around with the themes in Drupal 7 and changed it from the default "seven" to "Garland" and it at first even my even calendar was acting up and wouldn't let me open the date picker but I fixed that but now when I click on the top admin choices: dashboard, content, structure, appearance,people, module, configuration, reports and help i need to click on it and refresh the page for the options to open up. If I don't hit refresh it just wont load. Please help.

Comment: I think you disabled overlay module in the modules section. Enable it so that you can view the overlay.

Comment: Did you use any module for admin theme, like [admin_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu)?

Comment: sorry for the late reply but yes I switched from the default bartik theme to stark and thats when the problems arose.